# Book about a young man becomes a magician and soldier

Tags: story-identification, magic

I read this novel about about 10-12 years ago (mid-2000s). I can't recall if was a Young Adult book or aimed at an older audience.

A young man meets an old man who teaches him magic. At some point an evil magician tracks the old man who turns himself to stone to save himself. 
While this happens the young man signs up to the army.

At some point he is in jail for a night and confides in a friend that he knows some magic and makes a stone give out light so they can see. The first book ends with him killing an evil king(?) who gets magic from an amulet, this is during a battle at the end.

Earlier in the book he gets a blacksmith to forge a sword with a silver hilt and he imbues the silver with magic, as silver is the only material that can hold magic.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: And please add some paragraph breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Think you are talking abut the *[Darkweaver Legacy](http://www.markrobsonauthor.com/books/darkweaver-series/)* series by Mark Robson, the first book being *[The Forging of the Sword](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1644910.The_Forging_Of_The_Sword)*.

[image: The Forging of the Sword - book cover]

> Calvyn, a young farmers son comes home after a morning of fishing to find his entire village has been destroyed. Distraught he tags along with an old man who has a few tricks hidden up his sleeve. When a chance encounter with a man from Perdimon's (the old man) past forces Calvyn to make his own way in the world he joins a local Baron's army.

A slightly longer summary (and an excerpt from the book) can be found at [this review](http://www.mrsmad.com/bookmain.asp?ID=962):

> Calvyn's life changes forever when he meets Perdimonn, an old man who is not what he seems. Leaving his old life behind him, Calvyn sets out to travel with his mentor learning all he can about magic. When fate steps in and he must leave his friend, Calvyn decides to join the army of a local baron, and so his training as a soldier begins. New friendships and growing skills both in fighting and the art of magic quickly develop in the young man, but will he be ready to face 'the Chosen One' in battle?

Comment: Can you add any more details that suggest a similarity?

Comment: Thank you so much this sound like the one I am looking for.

Comment: @Eddyboi479: When you return, don't forget to click on the checkmark to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

The Darksword trilogy has an amulet, forging a magic sword and a mage getting turned to stone by an evil wizard.

[DarkSword Trilogy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darksword)

Comment: The series sounds good but not the one I'm looking for. The young man later in the books turns more towards magic and is not a king (well not that I found out only got to the second book)